# Fundamental groupoid of a contractible space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, groupoids

I read that the fundamental groupoid of a contractible space is indiscrete. How can one show this? I found this as an exercise [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~oantolin/groupoids/ps2.html).

Comment: What is the definition of an indiscrete groupoid?

Comment: It means every object is uniquely isomorphic to every other object - so the problem is the same as showing that all paths between two points are homotopic.

Comment: Note that a homotopy of maps $F_t:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$ gives a natural isomorphism between the induced functors $\pi F_0,\pi F_1:\pi(X,A)\to\pi(Y,B)$. Applying this to the composition of the maps $r:X\to*$ and $i:*\to X$ which is homotopic to $1_X$, you get a natural isomorphism between the identity functor on $\pi X$ and a constant functor. This should imply that $\pi X(x,y)$ is a singleton.

Comment: Hm I think I see what you are saying, thanks. Perhaps this boils down to: any connected groupoid with trivial automorphism groups (of its objects) is indiscrete.

Comment: Yes, this is a general fact about groupoids: In a connected groupoid there is a bijection between any two hom-sets.

Comment: The part I am surprised about is that two paths $f,g$ are homotopic rel endpoints if the corresponding loop $f*g^{-1}$ is nulhomotopic. I would not know how to construct the path-homotopy using the nulhomotopy of the loop.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention that this bijection can be chosen to be an isomorphism if the hom-sets are object groups (the group of endomorphisms on an object).

Comment: Sorry, I'll be back in half an hour, and will write an enlightening comment then ;-)

Comment: Algebraically, since we have $[f]=[f]*([g]^{-1}*[g])=([f]*[g]^{-1})*[g]=[g]$. Replacing the $=$ by $\simeq$, and noticing that we can concatenate a path homotopy with a path, this gives you an idea on a homotopy between $f$ and $g$.

Comment: However, if we were to construct a homotopy directly, it would probably look a bit different. Note that $f*g^{-1}$ is a map from $S^1=\partial D^2$ to $X$, and a nullhomotopy can be seen as an extension of $f*g^{-1}$ to the disk $D^2$. Now sliding the upper half-circle (where the map restricts to $f$) across the disk to the lower half-circle (where it restricts to $g$) gives you a path homotopy from $f$ to $g$.

Comment: Thank you, that explains everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f:(X,A)\to(Y,B)$ is a map of pairs of spaces, it induces a morphism $\pi f:\pi(X,A)\to\pi(Y,B)$ between their fundamental groupoids (with base points in $A$ and $B$, respectively). This actually gives a functor from the category of pairs of spaces to the category of groupoids.

Now if $F:(X\times I,A\times I)\to (Y,B)$ is a homotopy, this induces a functor
$$
\pi(X,A)×\mathbf I\to\pi(X,A)\times\pi I\to \pi(X×I,A×I)\to\pi(Y,B)
$$
Here $\mathbf I$ is tree groupoid with two objects, the fundamental groupoid of $I$ with base point $0$ and $1$. The middle map is a canonical isomorphism between the product of fundamental groupoids and the fundamental groupoid of the product.
A morphism $f:G\times\mathbf I\to H$ of groupoids is called a *homotopy*, with $\mathbf I$ playing for groupoids the same role as the unit interval does for spaces. Such a homotopy is basically a natural isomorphism between the restrictions of $f$ on $G\times\{0\}$ and $G×\{1\}$, with the arrows $f(1_x,0\to 1)$ as components.

Now let $X$ be a contractible space, and let $Y$ be the one-point space. We have maps $r:X\to Y$ and $i:Y\to X$ such that $ir$ is homotopic to $1_X$. Thus the identity on $\pi X$ is naturally isomorphic to a constant morphism $\pi X\to\{x_0\}$. From this it follows that each $\pi X(x,y)$ has precisely one element.

Comment: I like this way of thinking about things, but it is also nice to have your short comment above: $Hom(x,y) \cong Hom(x,x) = \pi_1(X,x)$, so having an indiscrete fundamental groupoid is the same thing as being simply connected.